# DataAdapter .Update does not update back table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

my problem is very common, but I have not found any solution.
This is my code:

```
public async Task<QueryResult> RollbackQuery(ActionLog action)
{
    var inputParameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameter[]>(action.Values);
    var data = DeserailizeByteArrayToDataSet(action.RollBackData);

    using (var structure = PrepareStructure(action.Query, action.Query.DataBase, inputParameters))
    {
        //_queryPlanner is the implementor for my interface
        return await _queryPlanner.RollbackQuery(structure, data);
    }
}
```

I need to load DataTable (from whereever) and replace data to database. This is my Rollback function. This function use a "CommandStructure" where I've incapsulated all SqlClient objects. PrepareStructure initialize all objects

```
//_dataLayer is an Helper for create System.Data.SqlClient objects
//ex: _dataLayer.CreateCommand(preSelect) => new SqlCommand(preSelect)
private CommandStructure PrepareStructure(string sql, string preSelect, DataBase db, IEnumerable<Parameter> inputParameters)
{
    var parameters = inputParameters as IList<Parameter> ?? inputParameters.ToList();

    var structure = new CommandStructure(_logger);
    structure.Connection = _dataLayer.ConnectToDatabase(db);
    structure.SqlCommand = _dataLayer.CreateCommand(sql);
    structure.PreSelectCommand = _dataLayer.CreateCommand(preSelect);
    structure.QueryParameters = _dataLayer.CreateParemeters(parameters);
    structure.WhereParameters = _dataLayer.CreateParemeters(parameters.Where(p => p.IsWhereClause.HasValue && p.IsWhereClause.Value));
    structure.CommandBuilder = _dataLayer.CreateCommandBuilder();
    structure.DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    return structure;
}
```

So, my function uses SqlCommandBuilder and DataAdapter to operate on Database.
PreSelectCommand is like "Select * from Purchase where CustomerId = @id"
The table Purchase has one primaryKey on ID filed

```
public virtual async Task<QueryResult> RollbackQuery(CommandStructure cmd, DataTable oldData)
{
    await cmd.OpenConnectionAsync();

    int record = 0;
    using (var cmdPre = cmd.PreSelectCommand as SqlCommand)
    using (var dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdPre))
    using (var cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapt))
    {
        dataAdapt.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        dataAdapt.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
        dataAdapt.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

        using (var tbl = new DataTable(oldData.TableName))
        {

            dataAdapt.Fill(tbl);
            dataAdapt.FillSchema(tbl, SchemaType.Source);

            tbl.Merge(oldData);
            foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
            {
                row.SetModified();
            }

            record = dataAdapt.Update(tbl);
        }
    }
    return new QueryResult
    {
        RecordAffected = record
    };
}
```

I Execute the code and I don't have any errors, but the data are not updated.
variable "record" contain the right number of modified (??) record, but..... on the table nothing

can someone help me?

**EDIT 1:**
With SQL Profiler I saw that no query is executed on DB. Only select query on .Fill(tbl) command.

**EDIT 2:**
Now I have made one change:

```
tbl.Merge(oldData) => tbl.Merge(oldData, true)
```

so I see perform the expected query but, with reversed parameters.

```
UPDATE Purchase SET price=123 where id=6 and price=22
```

instead of

```
UPDATE Purchase SET price=22 where id=6 and price=123
```